# Sending a form via php - echo is working but no email?

Tags: php

I have a basic form and the most basic .php file, the echo function is working but I am not receiving an email. I know this has been asked a lot but I cant seem to find an answer for my problem. Any help is appreciated. See bellow for code.

Tom

HTML:

```
<form class="contact" action="send.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group" id="red-border-focus">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input name="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" 
placeholder="First name">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input name="surname" type="text" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Last name">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="red-border-focus">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" name="number" class="form-control" 
placeholder="07000 123456">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="red-border-focus">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" 
placeholder="name@example.com">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="red-border-focus">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <textarea type="textarea" name="feedback" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Comments..." rows="7"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">`
</form
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$feedback = $_POST['feedback'];

$to="tom.b.flaherty@hotmail.co.uk";
$subject="Automated Email from evotherapycornwall.co.uk";
$body="This is an automated email: \n $firstname \n $surname \n $email \n\n 
$number \n\n $feedback";

mail($to, $subject, $body);

echo "Message sent! <a href='index.html'>Click Here</a> To Go Home";


?>
```

Comment: check output of mail function like `print(mail($to, $subject, $body)); die;` It will show you 1 if email sent successfully else will show 0 for failure. Also you can check email in spam as sometime it appears there due to server or unauthenticated SMTP details.

Comment: are you using phpmailer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a from header to your emails? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
<?php

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$feedback = $_POST['feedback'];

$to="tom.b.flaherty@hotmail.co.uk";
$subject="Automated Email from evotherapycornwall.co.uk";
$body="This is an automated email: \n $firstname \n $surname \n $email \n\n 
$number \n\n $feedback";
$from="From: webhost@email.com";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);

echo "Message sent! <a href='index.html'>Click Here</a> To Go Home";


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the mail function you must have configured an SMTP server such as sendmail or postfix. If you are using windows, you should consider using [PHPmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class and use another mail server(like gmail) for relay.

In your code you can verify if the mail function was able to deliver the message to your local mail server.

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $body)){
    echo "Message sent! <a href='index.html'>Click Here</a> To Go Home";
}else{
   echo " Error Sending Email";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mail PHP requires headers, so without cannot send emails, even if there are no errors to screen to see, the Php engine refuses to deliver your email message... I'm quite sure that the cause of this are the missing headers! See my example to correct delivery your email...

```
<?php
  $mail = "to_your@email.com"; // put here your recipient
  $fmail = "the_sender@email.com";  // put here your sender
  $headers = "From: $fmail" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $fmail" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "Return-Path: $fmail" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; Charset=\"UTF-8\"" . PHP_EOL;
  $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
  $subject = "Your Subject Here!";
  $message = "Hello! How are You?" . PHP_EOL;
  if (!@mail($mail, $ubject, $message, $headers, "-f$fmail")) {
    echo "Your Message Cannot Be Sent";
  } else {
    echo "Your Message is Sent with Success";
  }
?>
```

I'm using PHP_EOL constant because it's cross-server and should works fine on every system... If you need you can add to the top of your script this...

```
//=======================================//
//        Define PHP_EOL if not set      //
//=======================================//
if (!defined('PHP_EOL')) {
  if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'WIN')) {
    define('PHP_EOL',"\r\n");
  } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'MAC')) {
    define('PHP_EOL',"\r");
  } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'DAR')) {
    define('PHP_EOL',"\n");
  } else {
    define('PHP_EOL',"\n");
  }
}
```

You can read the requirements in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Final Notes: if you are under windows you can consider to use:

https://www.glob.com.au/sendmail/

https://msmtp.sourceforge.net/

Hope this help.